# If $A\subset [0,1]$ is strong measure zero, then $f(A)$ is strong measure zero where $f\colon [0,1]\to \Bbb{R}$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

> Let $f\colon [0,1]\to \Bbb{R}$ be a continuous function and $A\subset[0,1]$ be a strong measure zero set. Prove that $f(A)$ is also strong measure zero.

My attempt:
Let $(\varepsilon_n)_n\in \Bbb{R}_+^{\Bbb{N}}$. Since $f$ is continuous on a compact interval, it is absolutely continuous and
$$\begin{equation}\forall n\in\Bbb{N},\exists\delta_n>0, \forall x,y\in[0,1],\;  |x-y|\leq\delta_n\implies |f(x)-f(y)|\leq\varepsilon_n\label{1}\tag{1}\end{equation}$$
Consider the sequence $(\delta_n)_n\in\Bbb{R}_+^\Bbb{N}$ from ($\ref{1}$). Since $A$ is strong measure zero, let $(I_n)_n$ be a sequence of intervals (without loss of generality, compact) such that $(A\subseteq\bigcup_nI_n)\land (\forall n, \mu(I_n)\leq \delta_n)$. It is then the case that $\forall x,y\in I_n,\; |x-y|\leq \delta_n$ which allows to conclude that $\forall x,y \in I_n,\; |f(x)-f(y)|\leq \varepsilon_n$. Equivalently, $\forall a,b\in f(I_n),\; |a-b|\leq \varepsilon_n$ so, since $f$ is continuous and $I_n$ is an interval, $\mu(f(I_n))\leq\varepsilon_n$.

We conclude by pointing out that, if $A\subseteq\bigcup_n I_n$, then $f(A)\subseteq \bigcup_nf(I_n)$ and that $f(I_n)$ is an interval since $f$ is continuous $\square$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: @ChoripánConPebre, continuity on a compact interval does not imply absolutely continuity, indeed it just implies uniformly continuity. Nevertheless $(\ref1)$ is correct because of uniformly continuity.

Comment: @Angelo, thanks, got my words mixed up.