# No perfect non-empty set in $\mathscr{P}(\Bbb{R})$ can be strong measure zero.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, cantor-set

Here is what to be proven:

> No perfect non-empty set in $\mathscr{P}(\Bbb{R})$ has strong measure zero.

The textbook (Teoría de la Medida, Jaime San Martin Aristegui, section 1.6) suggests the following approach:

1. Suppose that $f\colon [0,1]\to \Bbb{R}$ is a continuous function and $A\subset [0,1]$ a strong measure $0$ set. Prove that $f(A)$ is also a strong measure $0$ set.
2. Show that every perfect set $A\subset [0,1]$ (not empty) contains a set $F$ homeomorphic to the Cantor set and therefore $A$ can't be a strong measure $0$ set.

I have already proven 1 but have no idea how to prove 2; in fact, I don't think it's true (intuitively, I'm not saying that the text book is wrong). Any hints or solutions are more than welcomed.

---

The solution to the first point is available at this post,  [If $A\subset [0,1]$ is strong measure zero, then $f(A)$ is strong measure zero where $f\colon [0,1]\to \Bbb{R}$ is continuous.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4520689)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we have a perfect nonempty set $A\subseteq [0,1]$. Call an interval $[a,b]$ proper if $a\not=b$.

- $A$ contains a proper interval.
  Since a proper interval is homeomorphic to $[0,1]$, which contains the Cantor set, $A$ contains a set that is homeomorphic to the Cantor set.
- $A$ does not contain any proper interval. We will prove that $A$ is homeomorphic to the Cantor set.

  [Recall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set#Construction_and_formula_of_the_ternary_set) that the Cantor set $\mathcal {C}$ is created by iteratively deleting the open middle-third part from a set of closed intervals, starting from $[0,1]$. Let us show that $A$ can be obtained similarly by iteratively deleting the open "middle-third part" from a set of closed intervals, starting from $[A_0,A_1]$, where $A_0=\inf\,(A)$ and $A_1=\sup\,(A)$. Since $A\subseteq[0,1]$ is nonempty and closed, $A_0$ and $A_1$ are in $A$ and $A\subseteq[A_0, A_1]$. Since a nonempty space that has no isolated points contains more than $1$ point, $[A_0, A_1]$ is a proper interval.

  ###### Middle-third part with respect to $A$

  Call a proper interval $[a,b]$ an  $A$-interval if $a, b\in A$ and $(a-\epsilon,a)\cap A=(b,b+\epsilon)\cap A=\emptyset$ for some $\epsilon>0$.
  Let $[a,b]$ be an $A$-interval. Since $A$ does not contain $[a+\frac{b-a}3,b-\frac{b-a}3]$, there is a point $m$ in that interval that is not in $A$. Let $m_-=\sup\,\{x\in A \mid x\lt m\}$ and $m_+=\,\inf \{x\in A \mid x\gt m\}$. Since $A$ is closed, $m_-$ and $m_+$ are in $A$. $\,m\in(m_-,m_+)$. $\,(m_-, m_+)\cap A=\emptyset$. So, $(m_-, m_+)$ is the maximal open interval containing $m$ that is disjoint from $A$.

  Call the open interval $(m_-,m_+)$ the middle-third part of $[a,b]$ **w.r.t. $A$**. There might be many such intervals; any one will do. 
  Since $a\in A$  is not an isolated point, $[a,m_-]$ is a proper interval and hence an $A$-interval. So is $[m_+,b]$.

  ###### Construction of space $\mathscr A$

  For iteration $0$, there is $1=2^0$ $A$-interval $[A_0, A_1]$.

  Let $(A_{\frac13}, A_{\frac23})$ be the middle-third part of $[A_0, A_1]$ w.r.t. $A$. Delete $(A_{\frac13}, A_{\frac23})$ from $[A_0, A_1]$, leaving two $A$-intervals: $[A_0, A_\frac13]$  and $[A_\frac23, A_1]$. This is iteration $1$, with $2^1$ disjoint $A$-intervals present.

  Next, let $(A_\frac19, A_\frac29)$ be the middle-third part of $[A_0, A_\frac13]$ w.r.t. $A$ and let $(A_\frac79, A_\frac89)$ be the middle-third part of $[A_\frac23, A_1]$ w.r.t. $A$. Delete these two middle-third parts, leaving four intervals: $[A_0,A_\frac19]\cup [A_\frac29,A_\frac13]\cup [A_\frac23,A_\frac79]\cup[A_\frac89, A_1]$. This is iteration $2$, with $ 2^2$ disjoint $A$-intervals present.

  Repeating this process infinitely. Note that the endpoints of all intervals at each iteration are in $A$.
  Denote the set of points in $[A_0, A_1]$ that are never deleted by $\mathscr A$. Note that $\mathscr A$ is also the intersection of $A_n$ for all $n\ge0$, where $A_n$ is the union of all $2^n$ disjoint $A$-intervals at iteration $n$.

  ###### Show $A=\mathscr A$

  - Since no point in $A$ is ever deleted, $A\subseteq\mathscr A$.
  - At iteration $n$, the length of each interval is $\le(2/3)^n$.
    Suppose $x\in \mathscr A$.
    At iteration $n$, there is a interval with length $\le(2/3)^n$ that contains $x$. Since both endpoints of that interval are in $A$, there is a point in $A$ that is $\le(2/3)^n$ away from $x$. So $x$ is a limit point of $A$.
    Since $A$ is closed, we must have $x\in A$.

  Hence, $A=\mathscr A$.

  ###### Homeomorphism

  Let $h_{0,0}:(\frac13, \frac23)\to(A_\frac13, A_\frac23)$ be the linear map that maps  $\frac13$ to $A_\frac13$ and $\frac23$ to $A_\frac23$ restricted to $(\frac13, \frac23)$.
  Let $h_{0,1}:(\frac19, \frac29)\to(A_\frac19, A_\frac29)$ be the linear map that maps $\frac19$ to $A_\frac19$ and $\frac29$ to $A_\frac29$ restricted to $(\frac19, \frac29)$. Let $h_{1,1}:(\frac79, \frac89)\to(A_\frac79, A_\frac89)$ be the linear map that maps $\frac79$ to $A_\frac79$ and $\frac89$ to $A_\frac89$ restricted to $(\frac79, \frac89)$.
  Repeating the construction of $h{*,*}$ infinitely, each time mapping linearly each deleted interval during [the construction of the Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set#Construction_and_formula_of_the_ternary_set) to the corresponding deleted interval during the construction of $\mathscr A$.

  It can be seen that combining all $h_{*,*}$, we have defined a uniformly-continuous strictly-increasing map on an open set of $[0,1]$ that is dense in $[0,1]$. Hence, with some care taken at the boundary $0$ and $1$, it extends to a continuous strictly-increasing map from $[0,1]$ to $[A_0, A_1]$ that maps $0$ to $A_0$ and $1$ to $A_1$. That is, it extends to a homeomorphism $h$ from $[0,1]$ to $[A_0, A_1]$.

  Since $h$ maps the deleted intervals during the construction of the Cantor set to the deleted intervals during the construction of $\mathscr A$, $h$ also maps the complement of the union of the former with respect to $[0,1]$ to the complement of the union of the later with respect to $[A_0, A_1]$.
  That is, $h$ maps the Cantor set $\mathcal C$ to $\mathscr A=A$.

  Hence, $\mathcal C$ and $A$ are homeomorphic.

Comment: +1. More generally, any non-empty completely-metrizable space with no isolated points has a subspace homeomorphic to the Cantor set.